# php: call python script with "*" as argument

Tags: php, python, arguments, call

I am trying to call a python script through php, but one of the arguments is getting passed as a reference? I want to pass `"*"` but when it gets to the python script, it turns into `"attempt.php"` which is my php files name. How could I fix this to pass just the `"*"`
This is the code I send (with 3 variables and one of them is the `"*"`)

```
$python = `python test.py $a $b $c`;
```

Comment: @KDOT That doesn't show how to prevent wildcards from being expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is a wildcard in the shell, you need to escape it. Use `escapeshellarg`.

```
$aesc = escapeshellarg($a);
$besc = escapeshellarg($b);
$cesc = escapeshellarg($c);
$python = `python test.py $aesc $besc $cesc`;
```